# How to send 8 bits binary data to serial port

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, serial-port

I have to send data in binary format and also have to receive on the other end in binary format.  I have sent data from serial port but don't know how to send binary data to serial port.  Is this right way to write the 8 bits binary data/byte to serial port.Please anybody help. thanks in advance.

```
port = new SerialPort("COM1", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
port.DtrEnable = true;
port.RtsEnable = true;
port.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
port.ReadTimeout = 6000;
port.WriteTimeout = 5000;
port.Open();
byte[] b={0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1};
port.Write(b, 0, 8);
```

Comment: `byte`s are not bits.

Answer (score 1):

So the thing is that you can only send bytes not bit.
If so what you should do is add your bits together to one byte:

0110 1101 = 0x6D

now you do:

```
byte[] b;
b[0] = 0x6D;
port.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
```

on the receiving side you read the one byte and get the single bits with a bit mask;

```
bool bit0 = read_byte & 0x01;
bool bit1 = read_byte & 0x02;
bool bit2 = read_byte & 0x04;
bool bit3 = read_byte & 0x08;
bool bit4 = read_byte & 0x10;
bool bit5 = read_byte & 0x20;
bool bit6 = read_byte & 0x40;
bool bit7 = read_byte & 0x80;
```

you can also do this with a loop if you want an array.

Comment: can u plz explain any of the line to get bit on receiving side code and receiving side code is byte specific code??

Answer (score 0):

Yes this works. You can send any raw binary values that you want. Also, instead of writing;

```
byte[] b={0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1};
port.Write(b, 0, 8);
```

You can simply write

```
byte[] b={0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1};
port.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
```

Comment: This is wrong. The OP explicitely asks to write a single byte to the serial port. You are declaring a `byte[]` with 8 `bytes`. This is different from declaring a `byte` containing 8 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create 8 *bytes* if you need 8 *bits*. The correct way to do this is to create a single `byte` consisting of your 8 bits, send it over the serial port and then use `&` and `>>` on the other side to receive the bit value, which will be either 1 or 0, ofcourse.

On the sender side;

```
       byte[] b = new byte[1];
       b[0] = 0x12; //your byte "00010010" here.
       port.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
```

On the retriever side;

```
       // lower nibble
       int bit0 =  receivedByte & 0x01;
       int bit1 = (receivedByte & 0x02) >> 1;
       int bit2 = (receivedByte & 0x04) >> 2;
       int bit3 = (receivedByte & 0x08) >> 3;
       // higher nibble
       int bit4 = (receivedByte & 0x10) >> 4;
       // etc.
```

Comment: thanks but i actually have to convert a string to byte and and what is 0b at the start in byte[0].

Comment: Can you give an example of a string? Is it something like "01011010"? The 0b stands for the binary representation, as does 0x for hexadecimal representation. After a quick lookup I found that C# doesn't support this, I'll edit the code.

Comment: Take each char from the string, multiply its position with 2 and add it to a sum of its a 1. You can do that on your own.

Comment: for which u r telling this method for string to byte conversion?

Comment: Yes, for converting the string to decimal value. You can use the decimal value as a byte.